# Randomly Failing Azure SignalR Auction Hub Method

Tags: azure, c#, asp.net

Thank you ahead of time.
I can't figure this out. It worked 100% of the time with the local signalr but if I use the Azure Signalr service it randomly has an error like this:
Error: There was an error invoking Hub method 'auctionhub.JoinGroup'.

Even that method is very simple and fails randomly.
In the AuctionHub.cs:

```
public Task JoinGroup(string id)
{
    return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, id);
}
```

I made a sample video: http://youtu.be/SjhiPBb1Q8Q?hd=1

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Azure Signalr needs a unique application name for each application.
Even having tested it on my local machine and deploying it on the server caused it to randomly fail.
app.MapAzureSignalR("needs to be unique", hubConfiguration);